# Moving ASP.net webservices to WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am verifying my login authentication using ASP.net webservices. But the client requested to move to WCF.

I need to know in what way WCF differs from ASP.net webservices.

What are the advantages for me to use WCF than ASP.net webservices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently there was an episode about that topic on Dime Casts.NET:

[Episode #73 - Migrating from .asmx web services to WCF web services](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/74)

Also this article might be useful:

[All About ASMX 2.0, WSE 3.0, and WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163674.aspx) by Aaron Skonnard

And the answers to the following question contain some good links:

[What are the benefits of using WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271326/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wcf)

Answer (score 2):

If your asmx is working fine then it's difficult to think of any "non-political" reasons for moving it over to WCF.

If the client is still adamant that is needs to be done then it should be a straightforward task.  WCF has a shallow initial learning curve, and it's easy enough to just "learn what you need".. exposing a few methods shouldn't take you long at all.