# What is WCF's performance like compared to other solutions for high volume programs?

Tags: wcf, performance

What is WCF performance like compared to other solutions such as ASMX or even a custom module?

Example: An online multi-player video game based on AJAX with JSON with data always going back and forth with the browser and server with hundreds of thousands to millions of users.

Comment: You might need to be more specific - is your example your actual scenario? You mention ASMX but that can't be used with JSON so I'm a bit unclear (did you mean ASHX?).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare ASMX against WCF, [there are several posts about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216931/what-is-the-difference-between-an-aspnet-web-method-and-a-wcf-service)...

Answer (score 0):

[WCF vs. WebSphere](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/6/486b4b4f-5a87-4b5c-beec-455290f83274/TradeBenchmark_WinServer2008.pdf).
This is a good detailed performance test based on the [.NET StockTrader Sample Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.aspx).

[ASMX vs. WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)