# Webservice in Window application Visual studio 2005

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2005

Can we add webservice(.asmx) to window application.When i go through File->New Project-> i cant see webservice template for addind.
But in File->New Web Site(for window application) we can easily add webservice

But when you go through this link codeproject.com/KB/webservices/… ,,there they are adding in window application side means File->New Project-> –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a Web Service in .NET...

You need to understand the wCF vs ASMX first, and for that I will point you to one of my answers regarding the subject.

[What is the difference between an asp.net web method and a wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216931/what-is-the-difference-between-an-asp-net-web-method-and-a-wcf-service/216992#216992)

after knowing that, you will know that ASMX Web Services require IIS to live, and for that, you will only find the template of a ASMX Web Service in a Web site project.

You can off course create a WCF Service, and you can host it anywhere you want, in IIS, as a Windows Service, as a TCP/IP service, as ... everywhere :)

Witch I thing is what you are after.

There are plenty of Video Tutorials outthere regarding WCF Services so you can see how to make and consume one.

Comment: But when you go through this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx ,,there they are adding in window application side  means  File->New Project->

Comment: thats a "New Project", it will not be in your WinForm project!! and if you follow up, you will see that you need to set up IIS as I mention.

Answer (score 1):

For a webservice to run, you need it to run under IIS, which your windows app isn't.

Do you want another app to be able to call a SOAP interface when your application is running?  Then in that case I think you may want your app to start a windows service.

Comment: But when you go through this link codeproject.com/KB/webservices/… ,,there they are adding in window application side means File->New Project-> –

Comment: some thing... you should read the complete URL that you posted before assuming anything!