# what is the difference between webservice and webapplication?

Tags: asp.net

can you please tell me what is the difference between webservice and webapplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, a Webservice uses special HTTP transport protocols to communicate to other servers.  Webservices are meant to be *used* by other applications.

In the ASP.Net world, a web application is a type of Visual Studio project that allows building ASP.Net websites in a particular configuration.  E.g. A Webservice can be built using a Web Application type project.  Or a Web Application can also refer to a website that is meant to be used directly by an end-user ( unlike web services ).

Here are a few links and related SO questions...

[What is the difference between an asp.net web method and a wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216931/what-is-the-difference-between-an-asp-net-web-method-and-a-wcf-service)

[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

[Introduction to Web Services and ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/825/)

Answer (score 21):

A web service:

- Typically returns XML or JSON or something like that, something that is easily decoded by a program
- The results you get from a web service is typically not just shown to a person in its raw form (ie. since it isn't HTML, the results have to be reformatted, like placed into a form)
- The intended usage of a web service is that it is something an application can talk to

A web application

- Typically returns HTML or image data or similar
- The results you get from a web application is usually shown to a person, through a web browser

As for similarities:

- Both typically use HTTP(S) as the transport
- Both typically use HTTP authentication/authorization to secure data
- Both are typically hosted by a web server

So the main difference is who usually talks to them. A web service usually by another application, a web application usually by a web browser. Other than that they're pretty similar.

Comment: Can a web application use web services?

Comment: Thanks. From reading, my understanding is that a web application can use web services in its servlets. The viewer can parse what the web services return using something like javascript. Am in understanding the relationships correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [Web Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) and here is [Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

**Web application**: any application which resides on a server, and mainly used by human using web browser. All user interactivity is done through web pages.

**Web service**: server-based application (as above) which may be accessed over the web via HTTP, but is meant primarily for interaction with other programs. Generally it is WEB API for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

check this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp